# bxslider different moveSlides

Tags: jquery, bxslider

So I configured my bxslider to start sliding automatically and just one elemet to move. Thats fine. But now i have also the controls to move left or right. The point is, i want that the slider moves 4 element when the controls are using.

So normal use: move one element 
User use: move 4 Element

Sounds so easy but i dont know how configure it out.

```
$('.carousel').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    slideWidth: 150,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,
    slideMargin: 15,
    moveSlides:1,
    pager:false,
    controls:true,
    moveSlides: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got some workaround for that. Just open the jquery.bxslider.js, row 1212 copy and enter the code and make some adjustments:

```
        el.goToNextFiveSlides = function(){
        // if infiniteLoop is false and last page is showing, disregard call
        if (!slider.settings.infiniteLoop && slider.active.last) return;
        var pagerIndex = parseInt(slider.active.index) + 5;
        el.goToSlide(pagerIndex, 'next');
    }
```

function -> **el.goToNextFiveSlides**  and **+5**

Now go to row 713 "Click next binding" and paste following code for **var clickNextBind**

```
        var clickNextBind = function(e){
        // if auto show is running, stop it
        if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto();
        el.goToNextFiveSlides();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

And just the same workaround for the "prev" function.

If you also so want that the auto slide never stops remove the if statement

```
if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto();
```